# Laravel 5 pivot table issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm not sure how to explain my problem but i'll give it a try.

I'm using Laravel 5 and i have 3 tables:

- pages
- languages
- language_page

This is what my models look like:
Page model:

```
public function languages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language', 'language_page')
                ->withPivot('title', 'content', 'slug', 'meta_title', 'meta_description')
                ->orderBy('main', 'desc');
}
```

Language Model:

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Page')
                ->withPivot('title', 'content', 'slug', 'meta_title', 'meta_description');
}
```

What i want to do return a record from the page table where language_id is a certain id, and where slug is a certain text.

This is what i got so far:  **EDIT:**

```
Page::with(['languages' => function($q) use($language_id, $slug) {
                        $q->where('language_id', $language_id);
                        $q->wherePivot('slug', $slug);
                    }])
                    ->first();
```

My problem:  how can i add a where clause with the column slug (from the pivot table language_page) ?

i hope this makes any sense at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent's BelongsToMany class has a

```
wherePivot()
```

method that allows you applying WHERE clauses to pivot table directly, see:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L111

Comment: i updated my question, that is what i changed it into, though the output of that will always be the first record (it ignores the where clause or something?)

Comment: Could you check what SQL is generated? Just replace ->first() with ->toSql() and dd() that value

Comment: hm weird.. this is what i get: "select * from `pages`", is it because i'm using the where's in languages and not directly in the pages table itself?

Comment: Are you sure the result is invalid? You filter by language_id and slug so it seems that only one page with given slug should exist for given language_id, right?

Comment: i didn't refresh properly the first time, the output of the dd() as the code is above is a page with the id of 1 (the first record, and with the slug/language_id whereclause it should be page id 2) and if i check the relations in the dd() languages turns out empty :S

Comment: It is ok that you see "Select * from pages" when you dump SQL. To understand that you need to know how Eloquent loads relations. It's a 3-step process: first query loads all matching Pages (Select * from Pages), then second query fetches relation for all matching Pages, and then Eloquent assigns fetched Languages to matching Pages. I checked the wherePivot and above code should work - please check if you apply correct criteria. You could also change first() to get() and see if results are correct.